# Joda: How to compare date instances in same time zone with different time zone representations?

Tags: jodatime

I am trying to compare two Joda dates for equality in my unit tests. `expected` is created with `new DateTime(...)` while `parsed` is parsed from a string with `DateTimeFormatter`.

Although my date string contains the timezone fragment `+02:00` the parsed date has the time zone `Europe/Berlin`. This is semantically correct (at least during DST), however the two dates do not `equal`.

I could, of course, create my expected time zone with `DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin")`, but that would not be totally correct IMHO. `Europe/Berlin` has an offset of `+01:00` during winter and `+02:00` during summer. The input string explicitly states `+02:00`, so my unit test would fail if the input date was in winter.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Example code**

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime expected = new DateTime(2013, 6, 22, 11, 7, 22, 123, DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(2));
String input = "2013-06-22T11:07:22.123+02:00";
DateTime parsed = formatter.parseDateTime(input);
System.out.println("expected: " + expected + " (" + expected.getChronology() + ")");
System.out.println("parsed  : " + parsed + " (" + parsed.getChronology() + ")");
System.out.println("equal   : " + expected.equals(parsed));
```

**Example output**

```
expected: 2013-06-22T11:07:22.123+02:00 (ISOChronology[+02:00])
parsed  : 2013-06-22T11:07:22.123+02:00 (ISOChronology[Europe/Berlin])
equal   : false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer myself. There's an option for `DateTimeFormatter` that prevents it from resolving time zone offsets:

```
ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withOffsetParsed()
```

Comment: Or you could convert both `DateTime` values to `Instant` values and compare those... but I suspect that without `withOffsetParsed` it may be completely ignoring the offset, and you'd get the wrong result if you had a very different offset in the string.

Comment: When I compare only timestamps then only the instance will be compared. 04:00+02:00 would be equal to 02:00Z, which is not what I need.

Comment: But it wouldn't be 02:00Z would it? Because you'd include the time zone in both. To be honest, it's a bit confusing exactly what you *are* expecting at this point.

Comment: I'm writing tests where I don't only want to assert that my object under test (let's assume a parser) returns the right instant (where `04:00+02:00` and `02:00Z` would be the same) but that it returns the correct timestamp in the corrent timezone.

Comment: But *timestamps* aren't inherently zoned. If it's really "when something occurred" then that's just an instant in time, and I think it's a bad idea to think of that as having a time zone at all. It depends on how you're going to use it, but life becomes a lot simpler when timestamps are viewed just as instants in time - for one thing there's then an obvious sort order.

Comment: Einstein would not agree. :-) "Timestamp" was a bad wording choice, since in my current use case I'm actually working with `DateTime` instances where the time zone is important (for display).

Comment: Okay - but then if the actual *time zone* is important, then the offset won't be enough either. If in your case the offset is enough, then I think we're probably at the end of the discussion :)

Comment: Agreed. :-) Thanks for your input! (by the way I totally agree with your general argument in favor for timestamps)